# Android Screen Sizes and Densities

Tags: android, screen

I am considering to drop support for small screens in my app.

Recently I have stumbled upon [Screen Sizes and Densities](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) and currently (2011-10-01) it says that 3.5 percent of the active devices fall into the small/hdpi category. I wonder what device actually has a small screen with high pixel density?

I know of the HTC Wildfire which has 240 x 320 pixels, 3.2 inches (~125 ppi pixel density). If I understand correctly that would be an ldpi device. For my app the Wildfire has a share of somewhere around 2 percent.

So first, why does Screen Sizes and Densities not list anything under small/ldpi? And second, what would be an example of a small/hdpi device?

Comment: You could try looking over this list of Android devices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Smartphones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some device from Dell like Aero which comes under small/hdpi.

HTC Tattoo can be considered under small/ldpi

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Basavraj's answer, Guessing the screen size is not that simple. Like Galaxy note has 1200 X 800 screen dimensions but it's screen size falls in large(and not in extra-large) category.